# USB Wifi card for Packet injection/Monitor mode

Tags: usb, linux, wifi

I'm searching for a USB wifi card which allows me to inject packages at a high rate (>6Mbit/s), as well as monitor them in Linux. If possible it should also support a high MTU (2300). Also, good or opensource drivers are needed as I need to get it running on an embedded ARM board.
Should be relatively small and lightweight and quite cheap as I need a lot of them.

EU Market

I don't care about fancy features like Hardware Crypto and 5G.

Basically, I search for a card which I can give a buffer and say:
Please send this on Channel x with a bitrate of y and the card will do it.
As well as say please listen on channel x with a bitrate of y and give me everything you receive, no matter how garbled it is.

I know two chipsets which work fine for my application, but one is discontinued (ralink rt2770f) and the other is PCIex not USB (Intel® Wireless-AC 9560).

Answer (score 0):

Any Alfa adapter will probably do. A popular one:

[Alfa AWUS036NHA](https://www.alfa.com.tw/products_detail/7.htm)

Trust me, their products work a lot better than their site looks.

Most of their products are available in Europe, the stronger ones not legal to use at full power though.

Answer (score -1):

The **Detroit DIY Electronics Wifi-5370-Antenna** might be an option: http://detroit-electronics.com/Wifi_Adapter_Dongle_For_Raspberry_Pi/wifi-for-raspberry-pi-antenna

> Chipset: RT5370
>
> Great for ethical hacking projects (this model supports packet injection).

Comment: I'm curious as to why this answer was down-voted. It seems like a perfectly valid stab at the question.

Comment: @BennettYeo Asking for a EU device and recommending a site titled Detroid-electronics might be it. No clue otherwise.